# Augmented Dickey Fuller Test for Stationarity

Tags: stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

[image]

[image]

How do I interpret this?

ADF t-value = -4.76
Critical Values
-2.57823    -2.883037   -3.47937

ADF t-value = -1.23
Critical Values
 -2.57823   -2.883037   -3.47937

Answer (score 2):

On the basis of your ADF teat I would conclude that your first series is stationary. You did not state which ADF test you used.  Looking at the first differences appear to be increasing as the series increases. Consider using a log transformation of the data.

On the basis of the ADF test the second series is non-stationary. The series looks as if it has a strong seasonal component which you should also consider

Comment: I disagree. To me, the first time series shows a dependence of the variance on time, violating a condition of stationarity. Therefore, regardless of what the ADF test says, I would not conclude it's stationary. The ADF test just tells me whether or not an AR process has a unit root. There are other ways to fail to be stationary.

Comment: @David White, I rarely comment on questions like this without some knowledge of the series being examined. If the series is increasing and the variability is increasing it is possible that the log-transformed series could be stationary about a trend. This is the case for many series in economics and should be looked at before concluding that the series is non-stationary.

Comment: I agree. Log transforming would sound appropriate in a case like that. And I might well run an ADF test after such a transform and after plotting the transformed data to see if it looks like it might reasonably be an ARMA process. It sounds like we're on the same page. I just got triggered by concluding stationarity on the basis of the ADF test alone. But I guess you meant stationarity after transformation.